# How to obtain seasonally-adjusted time series data using STL in Python

Tags: time-series, seasonality, decomposition, loess

On the section "STL decomposition" in the [2nd edition of Forecasting: Principles and Practice](https://otexts.com/fpp2/stl.html), it says that the `seasadj()` function can be used to compute the seasonally adjusted series but it does not say how this seasonally adjusted series is computed. I'm wondering how to do this in python's statsmodel package as there is no such `seasadj` function.

If I have an STL decomposition like so:
[image]

would the seasonally adjusted series be the `trend + remainder`? Just the `trend`?

In python:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import STL

stl_decomp = STL(series, period=12, seasonal=7).fit()
stl_seas_adj = stl_decomp.trend + stl_decomp.resid
```

Is this the correct way to compute the seasonally adjusted data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [statsmodels docs](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL.fit.html#statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL.fit), stl.fit() returns a DecomposeResult object. This has the estimated seasonal component of the time series decomposition. Subtracting this from the original time series should then provide you with a seasonally-adjusted time series.

Comment: which is effectively the same thing as `stl_seas_adj = stl_decomp.trend + stl_decomp.resid` then.

Comment: that is `stl_decomp.trend + stl_decomp.resid` = `stl_decomp.observed - stl_decomp.seasonal`

Comment: Correct. You can verify this in your code. Also, be aware of this method only working if it's additive. If the decomposition is multiplicative, neither way will work to get the seasonally adjusted data